# How to pass file path in JSON format

Tags: json

I have file path as 
D:\Working area for fle 50 with file comparison\Sample CSV\SampleSalesInvoice - limited columns-master.csv

I want to pass this value in JSON format.

Comment: That value is valid JSON anyway.

Comment: please give one example ...

Comment: I've a file with valid JSON, and what in this file is only :

`"D:\\Working area for sage 50 with file comparison\\Sample CSV\\SampleSalesInvoice - limited columns-master.csv"`

Comment: Yes it solved!   I forget to declare path variable as [DataMember]

Comment: It's not clear to me that this question is well-formed; it seems like a trivial statement, and from the previous comment it seems you have solved something, but we have no idea what. Can you please re-phrase the question and post the answer you used